# Sum of hours in multiple dates

Tags: php, symfony

I have an To make a sum of hours.

```
foreach ($horaires as $horaire) {

    $addition += strtotime($horaire->getPointNbh()->format('H:m:s'));

}
```

And it s not working. Somebody can help me about how to make operations on DateTimne Type with Symfony 2.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to make it using DateTime class methods? Wouldn't it be easier to create a query that performs that sum?

Comment: You have right but i am sure that it's easier this way and i would like to know how.

Comment: `strtotime()` returns a Unix timestamp. Is it really what you want? Can you please describe what is the type of `getPointNbh()`?

Comment: getPointNbh is a DateTime() And I tried without strtotime and not working!! My question is how can i make a cumul of hours in php on DateTime objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without Solution in side of Symfony or Datetime object, this is my solution:

```
    $heure = 0;
    foreach ($horaires as $horaire) {
        $heure += $horaire->getPointNbh()->format('H') *3600 + $horaire->getPointNbh()->format('i') *60 + $horaire->getPointNbh()->format('s');  ;
        //$heure = $heure * 3600;

    }
    $hour = floor($heure /3600);
    $min = floor($heure%3600/60);
    $sec = $heure - (($hour*3600) + ($min*60));
    $result = $hour.":".$min.":".$sec;

    return $result;
```